# Why authentication is failed after successfulyy validate token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I've created pretty simple IdentityServer based on OpenIdConnect concept.
My identity server after authentication returns to my app JwtToken.
When I trying to get access to authorized route, I have following logs:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[2]
>
> Successfully validated the token.

but below I have:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[7]
> OpenIdConnect was not authenticated. Failure message: Not authenticated

and I'm redirected to auth route in my IdentityServer.

Why is that?

Here is my client(not IdentityServer) configuration:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Audience = "http://localhost:5001";
            options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000"
            };
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.FormPost;
            options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ClientId = "user";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to authenticate off of bearer tokens with IdentityServer, look at using the IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation nuget package.

Your startup would look something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
      options.Authority = "IdentityServerURL";
      options.ApiName = "apiScope";
    });
```